# How to create hierarchy of employee in my organization

Tags: java, collections

I Want to create hierarchy of employee in my organization.
Actually i want to write a function which take employee as a input and give hierarchy from that employee.

> For Example, if I give 
>     **Employee[empCode=18234,Name=vipul,mailid=xyz@pqr.com] as input
>   then 
> it will return me hierarchy from 18234.**

I have **HashMap<Employee,Employee>** where 1st Employee working under 2nd Employee And 2nd Employee is E+1 of 1st.

**Can any one help me to select right collection type?
How can achieve this?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that as a first approach add fields `Employee manager` and `Collection<
Employee> employees` to your class `Employee`. So, you will get bi-directional multi tree structure when each employee knows both his manager and his employees (if any).

The CEO is employee too but his manager is `null`. The collection of employees of regular employee is either null or empty.

Comment: Thank AlexR, How will i search for particular employee in a collection?

Answer (score 0):

Like this?

- Create a class Employee
- Give it properties;String Name, Employee boss, String type (or ENUM)
- Add method addBoss(Employee boss)

`Empolyee e = new Employee();
e.addBoss(new Employee("Boss"));`

Then find the Employee you want, recursively get top Employee and work your way down. Then you should get the tree of the Employee.